# Scraping nested click-labyrinth with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape cookie-settings banners using Selenium. I would like to create a scraper that works for multiple websites without needing to adjust it for each website individually.

Let's take the cookie-settings banner of https://faz.net for example. I would like to extract the names of all cookies from this banner. The problem is that you have to navigate through the banner by clicking several "button" and "div" elements in order to load the HTML. Simply clicking through all "button" or "div" elements recursively won't work however because the clicks will load or unload other "button" and "div" elements.

Do you have any tips on how to approach this?

This is the python code to navigate to the cookie-settings banner of https://faz.net:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://faz.net")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@title,'SP')]")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='EINSTELLUNGEN']"))).click()
```

Comment: this example shows that creating scraper  for multiple websites is very big challange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie banner appears to have three main headers (in this case: `Zwecke`, `Funktionen`, and `Partner`), with each header possibly containing two immediate subtoggles, followed by the dropdowns. The dropdowns can have have cookies listed in a tabular format, or under subtoggles. This solution clicks each header, triggers the sub-buttons (if present), and toggles each dropdown:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.faz.net/aktuell/')
d.switch_to.frame(d.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#sp_message_iframe_510204")'))
d.execute_script('''document.querySelector('button[title="EINSTELLUNGEN"]').click()''')
time.sleep(2)
d.switch_to.default_content()
d.switch_to.frame(d.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#sp_message_iframe_192912")'))
results = []
for label in d.execute_script("""
   function* get_labels(){
      for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('div.pm-tab.focusable')){
         yield i.getAttribute('aria-label').toString()
      }
   }
   return [...get_labels()]
"""):
      d.execute_script(f'''document.querySelector('div[role="tab"][aria-label="{label}"]').click()''')
      time.sleep(1)
      for i in range(1, d.execute_script('''
         return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.pm-type-toggle > div')).length
      ''')+1):
            d.execute_script(f'''document.querySelector('div.pm-type-toggle > div:nth-of-type({i})').click()''')
            time.sleep(1)
            d.execute_script('''
               for (var j of document.querySelectorAll('.accordion')){
                  j.click();
               }
               for (var x of document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-vendor')){
                   if (x.querySelector('table') != null){
                       x.click();
                   }
               }''')
            for tbl in soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').select('table.tvtbl'):
               h, *vals = tbl.select('tr')
               hvals = [t.get_text(strip=True) for t in h]
               results.extend([dict(zip(hvals, [y.get_text(strip=True) for y in td])) for td in vals])
```

Output (first ten cookies from `results`):

```
print(results[:10])
```

Output:

```
[{'Cookie': 'b', 'Domain': '.blismedia.com', 'Dauer': '1 Jahr(e)'}, {'Cookie': 'id', 'Domain': '', 'Dauer': ''}, {'Cookie': 'fc', 'Domain': '.turn.com', 'Dauer': '180 Tag(e)'}, {'Cookie': 'optOut', 'Domain': '.turn.com', 'Dauer': '24855 Tag(e)'}, {'Cookie': 'clk', 'Domain': '.turn.com', 'Dauer': '180 Tag(e)'}, {'Cookie': 'bito', 'Domain': '.bidr.io', 'Dauer': '21 Stunde(n)'}, {'Cookie': 'bitoIsSecure', 'Domain': '.bidr.io', 'Dauer': '21 Stunde(n)'}, {'Cookie': 'b', 'Domain': '.blismedia.com', 'Dauer': '1 Jahr(e)'}, {'Cookie': 'id', 'Domain': '', 'Dauer': ''}, {'Cookie': 'b', 'Domain': '.blismedia.com', 'Dauer': '1 Jahr(e)'}]
```

Loading the results into `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

```
          Cookie           Domain         Dauer                 Category
0              b   .blismedia.com     1 Jahr(e)                      NaN
1             id                                                     NaN
2             fc        .turn.com    180 Tag(e)                      NaN
3         optOut        .turn.com  24855 Tag(e)                      NaN
4            clk        .turn.com    180 Tag(e)                      NaN
..           ...              ...           ...                      ...
580    _sp_v1_lt         .faz.net     30 Tag(e)  Notwendige Technologien
581   _sp_v1_opt         .faz.net     30 Tag(e)  Notwendige Technologien
582    _sp_v1_ss         .faz.net     30 Tag(e)  Notwendige Technologien
583   _sp_v1_uid  consent.faz.net     30 Tag(e)  Notwendige Technologien
584  consentUUID         .faz.net    365 Tag(e)  Notwendige Technologien

[585 rows x 4 columns]
```